# Handle Activity life cycle while calling on different phones

Tags: android, android-activity, callback, lifecycle

can any body tell me what will happen if application is in running state,if some one will call over your phone,then which call back method will be called up.

i have tested on different real android devices and also emulator.
1. samsung (sdous,grand):- call onpause method,but after approx. 10 second it will call onstop method.
2. xiaomi(redmi):- call onpause method,but after few milliseconds(0.6 second approx),it will call onstop method.
3. sony (xperiz d2005):- call onpause method,but after 1 second approx,it will call onstop method.
4. emulator:-call onpause method,but after few milliseconds(0.6 second approx),it will call onstop method.

please tell me whats going on in this case.thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior depends on free memory availability and handling strategy for different android version / device.
Sometimes you can just have onPause, sometimes you'll get onDestroy and complete process termination (losing all you static variables, background processes, loaders, etc) and later Activity restoration with onCreate(savedInstanceState != null).